# How do i map subcellular localizations to lower the number of classes to predict

Tags: proteins, gene-ontology

For a project, I want to predict the subcellular localization of some proteins. I am a student in software Informatics at the University of applied Science HEIG-VD.

Subcellular localization prediction is a common problem in the bioinformatics, but I have a problem

With the data I found. In this [database](http://locate.imb.uq.edu.au/downloads.shtml): of human and mouse proteins, we can [see](http://locate.imb.uq.edu.au/faq.shtml) that there are more than 30 different localizations.

At my level, and for the use of my exercise, 30 classes to predict is too much.

Where can I find a mapping to reduce those 30 classes to 4 or 5?

I tried QuickGO, to see the ancestor tree of the different classes, but nothing conclusive. Somebody might have done that, but I lack knowledge on bioinformatic web research.

There are the classes I wanted to map to reduce the number of classes :

- Cytoplasm (GO:0005737)
- Cytoplasmic Vesicles (GO:0016023)
- Endoplasmic Reticulum (GO:0005783)
- Endosomes (GO:0005768)
- Extracellular (GO:0005576)
- Golgi Apparatus (GO:0005794)
- Lipid Particles (GO:0005811)
- Lysosomes (GO:0005764)
- Melanosome (GO:0042470)
- Mitochondria (GO:0005739)
- Nucleus (GO:0005634)
- Peroxisome (GO:0005777)
- Plasma Membrane (GO:0005886)
- Synaptic Vesicles (GO:0008021)
- Cellular Component Unknown (GO:0008372)
- Apical Plasma Membrane (GO:0016324)
- Basolateral Plasma Membrane (GO:0016323)
- Centrosome (GO:0005813)
- Golgi Cis Cisterna (GO:0000137)
- Cytoskeleton (GO:0005856)
- Early Endosomes (GO:0005769)
- ERGIC (GO:0005793)
- Inner Mitochondrial Membrane (GO:0005743)
- Late Endosomes (GO:0005770)
- Medial-Golgi (GO:0005797)
- Outer Mitochondrial Membrane (GO:0005741)
- Secretory Granule (GO:0030141)
- Golgi Trans Cisterna (GO:0000137)
- Golgi Trans Face (GO:0005802)
- Tight Junction (GO:0005923)
- Transport Vesicle (GO:0030133)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to plot the first 10 GO categories of the the CC sub ontology (CC from cellular component). Or you can just visit [the official](http://amigo.geneontology.org/amigo/term/GO:0005575) webpage to see the list of children terms of them.

However there aren't only 4 or 5 categories, so you could arbitrary pick some of those.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one of those things where as long as you can justify your choice somewhat.

It might be worth seeing what others have done (see [loctree3](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4086075/) and [PSORT](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/26/13/1608/201357)) and seeing how well they match your case, then add in any subdomains you have a particular interest in.